# Handle async SQLite database row adding

Tags: android, sqlite, events

I'm developing application which consists of 2 parts: Activity and BroadcastReceiver. BroadcastReceiver handles incoming SMS and may create new rows in database.

I have a problem: if activity is opened and active while BroadcastReceiver adds new row to database - new row doesn't appear in activity's ListView.

I tried to use Cursor observers for listView's cursor, but that observer triggers notification on row change only. On new row adding that observer does nothing.

Here is code sample:

```
m_testCursor = m_dbAdapter.fetchAll();
m_testCursor.registerContentObserver(
    new ContentObserver(new Handler()) 
    {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
        {
            Log.w("my_tag", "test content changed");                    
        }
    }
);

m_testCursor.registerDataSetObserver(
    new DataSetObserver()  
    {
        @Override
        public void onChanged()
        {
            Log.w("my_tag", "test data set changed");                       
        }
    }
);

SimpleCursorAdapter checks = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.nodes_row, m_testCursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(checks);
```

Can I somehow handle new rows addition in Activity from BroadcastReceiver part? All I need is just to trigger one of my UI refresh methods.

Answer (score 0):

Does `checks` object available in the broadcast receiver? If so and if you need just the UI refresh method, I think you should simply call `checks.notifiDatasetChanged()` when dataset changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [setNotificationUri()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#setNotificationUri%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri%29) on your cursor and after the change in the db call [notifyChange()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) on the `ContentResolver`. To get the ContentResolver call `getContentResolver()`. Use the same uri in both calls

in your Activity

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://your_database");
m_testCursor = m_dbAdapter.fetchAll();
m_testCursor.setNotificationUri(getContentResolver(),uri)
```

in the database create/update/delete methods after change

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://your_database");
getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

You can also call `setNotificationUri()` directly in the `fetchAll()` method and defince the Uri as static final instance variable of your db class.